# how to center a form inside div?

Tags: css, html

```
<div class="header_upper_right">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Username" />
        <input type="password" name="Password"/>                        
    </form>
</div>
```

it's a simple form on my html what i want is how to make it look like the

```
======================
|                    |
|                    |  
|  pass       name   |
|                    |     
|                    |
======================
```

pass and name mean the text box
i hope that i make it clear, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting right and left margins of div to auto and a width on the form.